# Definition of complete binary tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, language-agnostic, binary-tree

(From: Data Structures Using C  By Aaron M. Tenenbaum):

> "A complete binary tree of depth d is the strictly binary tree all of whose leaves are at level d."

So, by that meaning the following tree should not be complete binary tree, right?

http://cs-study.blogspot.de/2012/11/complete-binary-tree.html

But, it is according to wikipedia: 
In a complete binary tree every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes in the last level are as far left as possible. It can have between 1 and 2h nodes at the last level h.

Please clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation:

- On level 1..d-1 there are only nodes, and all of them must exist.
- At level d, only leaves exists, and they must be filled from left to right
- Nodes without children are not considered leaves on level d-1